# Post to Page as another Page - Facebook API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.2

I'm looking to have my app post to a non-owned Page AS one of the user's owned pages (owned-page Posted to non-owned-page's feed).

If you log in to Facebook as your page, you are allowed to do this on the desktop platform. However, my trials (and search) have returned that it's "*not possible*" to execute via Facebook Graph API.

Specifically when I execute the following POST:

```
/{target-page-id}/feed?message=test&access_token={owned-page-access-token}
```

I receive the following response from FB:

> (#200) Posts where the actor is a page cannot also include a target_id\n         other than EVENT or GROUP

Posting to Event or Group works, but doesn't allow me to post to a target page.

Any workarounds? Having a hard time grasping that you can do it on the desktop portal but not via the API

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would guess you can't do it because either it haven't been added to the API or they figured that it would be used as spamming and didn't added it

Comment: "the figured that it would be used as spamming" - This is a valid point, but there are a ton of constructive uses for this method.

Answer (score 0):

You might try defining who is posting to the page by adding the query string: &from=[name of page]

Ex:

```
/{target-page-id}/feed?message=test&from=[PageName]&access_token={owned-page-access-token}
```